# Angular6 form validations

Tags: angular

Am performing form validations using angular6 documentations and for now I ensured that all form validations are filled but now

Here is my question:

1.) How do I validate that Password and Confirm Password input value is not less than 6 characters and that both password field and confirm password field must match

2.) How do I ensure that email address entered is valid

```
  <form #r="ngForm" name="theForm" (submit)="reg(r)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="username"
            [(ngModel)]="register.username"
            #registerUsername="ngModel"
            required
            pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$">
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="registerUsername.errors?.required && registerUsername.touched">
        The username is required
      </span>
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="registerUsername.errors?.pattern && registerUsername.touched">
        The username can only contain the letters a-z or A-Z
      </span>
    </div>





    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password"
            class="form-control"
            name="password"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="register.password"
            #registerPassword="ngModel">
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="registerPassword.errors?.required && registerPassword.touched">
        password is required
      </span>
    </div>



 <div class="form-group">
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="password"
            class="form-control"
            name="password"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="register.password"
            #registerPassword="ngModel">
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="registerPassword.errors?.required && registerPassword.touched">
        Re-enter password is required
      </span>
    </div>





   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email"
            class="form-control"
            name="email"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="register.email"
            #registerEmail="ngModel">
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="registerEmail.errors?.required && registerEmail.touched">
        Email is required
      </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: email addresses must be validated through the `email` attribute or through the `pattern` one. Seeing you're using template-driven forms, you will have to create a directive on the `form` tag to validate password matching. For the length, a `minlength` attribute will be enough.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Your suggestion really help me find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to implement the requirements you stated, below is the link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formvalidation-wins999-z1sxcw

I have used inbuilt validators for minimum length and to validate email

And a custom validator for password and confirm password match.

These links are useful:

https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

https://material.angular.io/

I hope it helps

Comment: now your solution and my solution works for the same purpose but am selecting your answer  for additional knowledge on angular materials. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to resolve it in case it might help someone.

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password"
            class="form-control"
            name="password"
            required  minlength="6"
            [(ngModel)]="register.password"
            #registerPassword="ngModel">
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="registerPassword.errors?.required && registerPassword.touched">
        The password is required
      </span>

 <span *ngIf="registerPassword.errors?.minlength  && registerPassword.touched">
        Password must be at least 6 characters or longer.
      </span>

    </div>



  <div class="form-group">
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="password"
            class="form-control"
            name="repassword"
            required  minlength="6"  pattern={{register.password}}
            [(ngModel)]="register.repassword"
            #registerRePassword="ngModel">
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="registerRePassword.errors?.required && registerRePassword.touched">
        Confirm password is required
      </span>

 <span *ngIf="registerRePassword.errors?.minlength  && registerRePassword.touched">
        Password must be at least 6 characters or longer.
      </span>

  <span *ngIf="registerRePassword.errors?.pattern  && registerRePassword.touched">
        Passwords must match.
</span>

    </div>



   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email"
            class="form-control"
            name="email"
            required  pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"
            [(ngModel)]="register.email"
            #registerEmail="ngModel" email>
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="registerEmail.errors?.required && registerEmail.touched">
        Email is required
      </span>


<span *ngIf="registerEmail.errors?.pattern  && registerEmail.touched">
       Valid Email is required
      </span>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use reactive forms in angular, to my mind it's more readable and flexible. You can start from [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). Your form will look like:

```html
<div [formGroup]="myForm" #form>
      <label>Username</label>
      <input formControlName="username" type="text">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input formControlName="password" type="password">
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
      <input formControlName="confirmPassword" type="password">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input formControlName="email" type="text">
      <button (click)="submit()" [disabled]="form.invalid">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Than build your form in .ts file using FormBuilder like that:

```js
myForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = builder.group( {
    username: [null, Validators.required],
    password: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
    confirmPassword: [null, Validators.required],
    email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
    }, {validator: PasswordValidator.matchPassword});
   }
```

To validate length, email and some more stuff you can use [built-in validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators), but for password matching you should write some more code. I wrote it in separates file PasswordValidator.ts. It looks like:

```js
export class PasswordValidator {
  static matchPassword(control: AbstractControl) {
    const password = control.get('password').value;
    const confirmPassword = control.get('confirmPassword').value;
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      control.get('confirmPassword').setErrors({matchPasswords: true});
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following.

Html.

```
          <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
              <input matInput type="password" formControlName="newpassword" placeholder="Enter new password"
                [type]="hide1 ? 'password' : 'text'" required minlength="4" maxlength="25"
                text="test" #newpassword>
              <mat-icon matSuffix class="pointer-style" (click)="hide1 = !hide1" >
                {{hide1 ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
                <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['newpassword'].hasError('required')">
                   New Password is <strong>required</strong>
                  </mat-error>
              <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['newpassword'].hasError('minlength')">
                Your password must be at least <strong>4 characters. </strong>
            </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>


            <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">

                <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" formControlName="conformpassword" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
                  [type]="hide2 ? 'password' : 'text'" text="test" #conformpassword>
                <mat-icon matSuffix class="pointer-style" (click)="hide2 = !hide2">
                  {{hide2 ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('notSame')">
                      Passwords does not match
                  </mat-error>

              </mat-form-field>
          <div class="full-width-input">

          </div>
          <button  style="margin-left: 75px;" mat-raised-button [disabled]="!form.valid" color="primary">SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
```

in component:

1. > import {ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material';
   >
   > ```
   > export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
   >
   >   isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective
   > | NgForm | null): boolean {
   >
   >     const invalidCtrl = !!(control && control.invalid && control.parent.dirty);
   >     const invalidParent = !!(control && control.parent && control.parent.invalid && control.parent.dirty);
   >
   >     return (invalidCtrl || invalidParent);   } } @Component({   selector: 'app-changepassword',   templateUrl:
   > './changepassword.component.html',   styleUrls:
   > ['./changepassword.component.scss'] }) export class
   > ChangepasswordComponent implements OnInit {   form: FormGroup;  
   > error = '';   formSubmitAttempt: boolean;   oldPassword:
   > FormControl;   newpassword: FormControl;   conformpassword:
   > FormControl;   hide: boolean;   hide1: boolean;   hide2: boolean;  
   > matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
   >
   > constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
   >
   >
   >         this.form = this.fb.group({
   >           oldPassword:  ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4),
   > Validators.maxLength(25)])],
   >           newpassword:  ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4),
   > Validators.maxLength(25)])],
   >           conformpassword:  ['']
   >
   >         }, {validator: this.checkPasswords });
   >         dialogRef.disableClose = true;
   >     }
   >
   >     checkPasswords(group: FormGroup) { // here we have the 'passwords' group
   >     let pass = group.controls.newpassword.value;
   >     let confirmPass = group.controls.conformpassword.value;
   >
   >
   >     return pass === confirmPass ? null : { notSame: true }   }
   >
   >
   >   ngOnInit() {
   >     this.hide = true;
   >     this.hide1 = true;
   >     this.hide2 = true;   }
   >
   > }
   > ```